# How to detect when two bitmaps intersect in Android

Tags: android

I made two bitmaps based off of two ImageViews using this code:

```
playerimage.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bplay1 = playerimage.getDrawingCache();
brickimg.buildDrawingCache(); 
Bitmap bbrick1 = brickimg.getDrawingCache();
```

I tried getting the height and width of each bitmap for collision detection, but it made the app crash. This is what I used for it:

```
int w1 = bplay1.getWidth();
int h1 = bplay1.getHeight(); 
int w2 = bbrick1.getWidth();
int h2 = bbrick1.getHeight();
```

Is there a different way to get the coordinates of a bitmap to test collision detection?

Comment: is anything getting executed in a thread ? maybe when you are trying to get image stats they are not loaded yet

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Rect.intersects(Rect, Rect), like this example:

```
Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
myView.getHitRect(myViewRect);

Rect otherViewRect1 = new Rect();
otherView1.getHitRect(otherViewRect1);

Rect otherViewRect2 = new Rect();
otherView2.getHitRect(otherViewRect2);

if (Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect1)) {
  // Intersects otherView1
}

if (Rect.intersects(myViewRect, otherViewRect2)) {
  // Intersects otherView2
}
```